# How to get the domain of a Partial Function in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is it possible to get the domain of a Partial Function in Scala?

Ex:

```
    val f: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = {

      case 1 => println("This is 1")

      case 2 => println("This is 2")

   }
```

Is there any way to get something like:

```
    val list = f.getDomain
```

which would indicate values 1 and 2?

**Update**: I am trying to build an notification system (event bus).
The subscriber will look like this:

```
    class SomeSubscriber extends Subscriber {

    notifications {

      case LoginEvent(date) => println("Login on " + date)

      case LogoutEvent(date) => println("Logout on " + date)

      case e: Notification[Any] => async {

         println("Other notification: " + e)

         ui {

          println("UI in async! " + e)

         }

       }

     }

   }
```

In my NotiticationService (the event dispatcher) I want to access the events declared in every 'notifications' block so I can push the notifications to the subscribers. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see how this can be possible (in a reasonable amount of computation, anyway. Consider a partial function defined only on prime numbers (so getDomain would need to return all prime numbers)

Comment: You got a point there. I was thinking that the Scala compiler will be able to help me somehow (in my example should be easy to retrieve the domain).Thanks.

Comment: If you want access to the domain, then use a `Map` instead.

Comment: Suppose you have a `PartialFunction` that works on a certain range of `Double`s. In what form would you expect the domain to be returned? Surely not a list of all possible `Double` values that it is defined at?

Comment: For a range of Double's I would aspect something like List[Range] (with Range.getMin, Range.getMax). I think that for a partial funtion declared inline you can find the domain at compile time. In my situation it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a collection, and you'd like to know which elements also belong to the domain of `f`, you can use `filter` and `isDefinedAt` like so:

```
scala> 1 to 10 filter f.isDefinedAt
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
```

This simply checks exhaustively. I don't know if there is any better way.

Comment: I was thinking to to that, but I though maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 4):

It's inherently impossible, since a partial function may be defined for any subset of the input range; the input range itself may not be finite, in which case the domain would not necessarily be finite either. You can only obtain the domain via an exhaustive match (per Dan's answer), however you cannot exhaustively search an infinite input space.

Comment: I think it would be useful to have the option of finding the 'fixed' domain values (by fixed I mean case on simple values). Or maybe to retrieve some sort of ranges of domain.

Comment: This would require some very ugly hacks in the compiler code and impossible to do in the general case anyway. On a personal level I don't feel this would be useful beyond a handful of special cases; there are cleaner ways to do this (such as registering all supported 'fixed' values in a map, per ziggystar's comment above).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the six year delay.

I do not believe that this problem can be solved with a map. The notifications have the form:

```
case LoginEvent(date) => ...
```

which involves a pattern that contains a variable date, whose value is unknown at compile time: it will be bound when the pattern matches during execution.

You actually do not want a list (or set) of domain values. You want to know the pattern, as I see it.

I have encountered this problem as well, and although it perhaps is a not a common problem, agreed, it does dive into the role of reflection in Scala: the ability to inspect the code from within the program. It concerns the distinction between shallow and deep internal DSLs. The above DSL is shallow, which causes this problem of not being able to analyze the code.